# Need to replicate a split toning (with a colored image)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-lightroom

I've been using the Split Toning functionality of Lightroom and Adobe Camera Raw for some time now -- you can see the effect in [this video](http://blog.infiniteskills.com/2012/08/adobe-photoshop-cs6-tutorial-split-toning/).

How would I go about performing adjustments like these in the core of photoshop? Note: I don't want to do this on a grayscale image, I want to adjust the hues of the shadows and highlights of a colored image.

Comment: It could be a good idea to post a screenshot from the video showing  the effect you want to achieve; your video link might not be accessible in the future!

Answer (score 1):

`Image > Adjustments > Color Balance`

will get you close. It's not as simple as a hue and saturation slider, but it does allow for color adjustments based upon shadows and highlights.

### Additional...

You could always use `Filter > Camera Raw Filter` from **within** Photoshop as well. Split toning is part of that filter.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I've resorted to using. Was hoping there was a more accurate implementation of it elsewhere :(

Comment: Edited to add additional... :)

Comment: Yeah that's the bit I'm trying to replicate /outside/ of the ACR tool ^_^

Comment: So you can't use the filter within Photoshop either??

Comment: Well, let me back up. I'm trying to write a comparable function in OpenGL shader language; I have no visibility into what that ST filter is doing, so I'm trying to figure out how to replicate it's functionality using the native Ps tools so I can better understand what it's doing.

Comment: Ahh.. okay, that sounds more like an SDK conversation.

Comment: Sadly, yeah. I'm trying that angle too, no luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "select > color range" tool with the highest fuzziness value. Select a dark tone somewhere around "75% grey."

Hide the selection so you can see better, and use "image >adjustments>selective color"; make adjustments to "neutrals" only.
Adjust saturation and/or levels as needed.

Deselect and then repeat using "25% grey" tone selection.

Answer (score 0):

(<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>) on Windows or (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>) on Mac will bring up Hue/Saturation panel. In this panel you get similar controls to fiddle with. Using a pair of layers you can achieve the desired results.